# ng-click odd behavior when using "var = !var"

Tags: angularjs, boolean, angularjs-ng-click

```
<accordion class="nested-accordion">
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in menu" is-open="item.opened" ng-if="item.children == true && item.grandchild == true">
          <accordion-heading id="inner-accordion">

         ---- PROBLEM HERE ----
            <div ng-click="item.opened = !item.opened" class="toggle-caret">
                  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play" ng-class="{true: 'caret-open', false:'caret-closed'}[item.opened]"></span>
              </div>


              <button class="btn-link filter-option" ng-class="{true:'option-checked', false:''}[item.checked]" ng-click="test(item, $event); $event.stopPropagation()">{{item.name}}</button>
          </accordion-heading>
                    <div>
                 <!--  some stuff here -->
                    </div>
                  </accordion-group>
                </accordion>
```

I am having an issue with the line I singled out in the code above. The ng-click is not toggling the **item.opened** from **true** to **false**. However, if I change the syntax from:

```
ng-click="item.opened = !item.opened"
```

to:

```
ng-click="item.opened != item.opened"
```

the accordion works as expected. This is not what I want though. 
Further more this is the only part out of the accordion that is experiencing this issue. Can anyone explain why this is giving me a hard time?

Comment: Did you try inside a function instead of directly in `ng-click` ?

Comment: `item.opened != item.opened` will always result in false - it's not an assignment, it's a comparison. x != x is never true.

Comment: Thats what I thought, and yet the toggle was working. I added single quotes around the variable though, and now it is working. But I have never had to add quotes before.

    ng-click=" 'item.opened' = '!item.opened'" is working.

But I am getting a console error of 

    Error: [$parse:lval] Trying to assing a value to a non l-value

I don't want to create a function for this because its simply a true/false boolean that is being adjusted.

Comment: I prefer to keep as much code as possible out of my HTML, so I'd drop a tiny function into my controller and call it.  I try to separate my concerns as best I can.  I get that this is just a variable toggle so you may not want to get too complicated.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your error in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/j5DN2meXgCOAwD43G2qI?p=preview) but the syntax works for me. Your problem might be some other watch, can you share a minimal example on a plunkr/fiddle?

Comment: Alright, so I walked away, came back to it, and found a source of my problem. The caret is not being captured as the open toggle. Its outside of the .accordion-toggle capsule.

Comment: your ng-class on caret is reverse, instead, you should do like 'caret-open': item.opened